# Getting error in importing the python file

Tags: python, import

I stored my python file in /home/system/Home/desktop/file.py

```
import file
```

> ImportError: No module named file

Comment: What is your current directory? If you are running from console, what is the output of `pwd`

Comment: try `sys.path.append(os.path.normpath("/home/system/Home/desktop/"))` and then `import file`

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: ouput of pwd is /home/system

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 2, then try this

```
import imp

file = imp.load_source('module.name', '/home/system/Home/desktop/file.py')
file.MyClass()
```

If you are on 3.4, use this

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

file = SourceFileLoader("module.name", "/home/system/Home/desktop/file.py").load_module()
file.MyClass()
```

Else if you use 3.5+, use this:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module.name", "/home/system/Home/desktop/file.py")
file = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(file)
file.MyClass()
```

PS: this solution is adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)